# Is there any way to track every user action in Odoo v8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, audit-trail, audit-logging

I installed auditlog, and smile_audit both looks similar but they just track the logs based on one module.

But I'm looking for all the modules in Odoo. Basically by a user.
I tried defining rules by

```
  Object: 'ir.model'
```

but that does'nt track anything.Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you tell me about the history tab which sounds to be better, because I need this data for some analysis purpose)

Answer (score 0):

**Audit Trail in OpenERP - (Odoo)**

In business there are number of users. It is tedious task for administrator to track all user's activity. Here OpenERP (Odoo) brings good feature to track user activity on any model. It means user perform any action [like create, modify, delete] on any model that all performed action can see administrator by logs. This feature is introduced in Audit Trail module

Audit Trail allows you to log every user operation on all system models. (such as sales, leads or products)

**Required module: - Audit trail**

- First you just need to install the Audit Trail module in OpenERP (Odoo). After installing it, you will see in the Reporting menu an Audit menu item

[image]

- To track user activity you need to create audit rule. Audit rules are specified on a particular model that you want and assign user that you want to track that activity. The rules tell the system which activities performed by the user need to be logged.

**How to create an audit rule :-**

**Navigate to : Reporting/Audit/Audit Rules**

**For example: -** I have created a rule for sale order model to track activity of sale_user

[image]

- To activate the audit rule you need to first 'Subscribe' to the audit rule.

[image]

- To test this, login with sale_user, make changes to any in sale order. I have just created a sale order to show logs.

[image]

- Now login with administrator. To see the logs of the activities performed on the sale order model by sale_user :-

**Navigate to : Reporting/Audit/Audit Logs**

[image]

- You will see a list of the changes made to the sale order model. Click on logs to see the changes sale_user made to the sale order. You can also check old values and new values for comparison.

You can track every user operation on all the objects of the system. [operation such as: create, modify, delete]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this module is not available for version 8? I tried 'auditlogs' and 'smile_audit' modules, in both of these modules activities are tracked based on one object instead of user.  @Jainik Patel

Answer (score 0):

Using openerp 8, install audit log module, then create a new rule, put "res.users", this will log every user action.